# Internal Server Error - The given id must not be null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this problem now and I would like to ask for help, I can't acess te value of `dto.getIdCliente()`, but this is passed like JSON for the `ServicoPrestadoDTO dto`.
Codes bellow...

ServicoPrestadoController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/servicos-prestados")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServicoPrestadoController {

    private final ClienteRepository clienteRepository;
    private final ServicoPrestadoRepository servicoPrestadoRepository;
    private final BigDecimalConverter bigDecimalConverter;

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ServicoPrestado salvar(@RequestBody ServicoPrestadoDTO dto){
        LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse(dto.getData(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        Integer idCliente = dto.getIdCLiente();

        Cliente cliente =
                clienteRepository.findById(idCliente)
                        .orElseThrow(() ->
                                new ResponseStatusException(
                                        HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Cliente não encontrado!"));

        ServicoPrestado servicoPrestado = new ServicoPrestado();
        servicoPrestado.setDescricao(dto.getDescricao());
        servicoPrestado.setData(data);
        servicoPrestado.setCliente(cliente);
        servicoPrestado.setValor(bigDecimalConverter.converter(dto.getPreco()));

        return servicoPrestado;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<ServicoPrestado> pesquisar(
            @RequestParam(value = "nome", required = false) String nome,
            @RequestParam(value = "mes", required = false) Integer mes
    ){
        return servicoPrestadoRepository.findByNomeClienteAndMes("%" + nome + "%", mes);
    }

}
```

ServicoPrestadoDTO.java:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ServicoPrestadoDTO {
    private String descricao;
    private String preco;
    private String data;
    private Integer idCLiente;
}
```

ServicoPrestado.java:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ServicoPrestado {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String descricao;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cliente")
    private Cliente cliente;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal valor;

    @Column
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDate data;
}
```

I don't undertand why is not getting the `servico` send by my `servico-prestado-form.ts` like JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ServicoPrestadoDTO` class has a field `idCLiente` and not `idCliente` (you have an uppercase "L").

Try changing it to the proper casing of `idCliente`.

Does that fix it for you?

Comment: Yes, this and the fact of I don't call the ``ServicoPrestadoRepository.save(servicoPrestado)``

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

While using lombok, add the `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation to your `ServicoPrestadoDTO` class.

This way, Jackson deserializer will be able to deserialize your JSON into an object.

Comment: It's because sometimes I can't have this JSON, and just have an empty response

Comment: Yes, but you could use both annotations. `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@NoArgsConstructor`

Comment: Yes I will add, thanks for your disponibilization